# Easiest possible way to backtest a semi dynamic options strategy

Tags: options, volatility, programming, backtesting

I have a few options strategies Id like to backtest and I have some familiarity with Python. In particular Id like to backtest a "semi-dynamic" long vol. strategy putting on $0$ cost backspreads in the direction of the market after a say $5 $% movement within a month.

A backspread is an option combo where one sells an option ATM and goes down in OTM until the premium of buying two matches that premium obtained from the selling. In this way the position is $0$ cost to enter, with twice as many options bought as sold.

Any ideas? Packages and so on.

Also feel free do run this backtest and give me the result! This would indeed be the easiest way.

Comment: http://gouthamanbalaraman.com/blog/quantlib-python-tutorials-with-examples.html

Comment: I'm not aware of any canned routines to do this.  Goes without saying calcing performance of an option portfolio is a little more complicated than cash equities.  Assuming you have historical options data though, it's a fairly straightforward implementation, I'd just code it myself if I were you.

Comment: In my experience, most well known python packages (eg. `backtrader`, `zipline`) are mostly optimised for 'cash'-style intraday trading where you know the securities of interest in advance and know their prices, but need to loop over many, many intraday bars. From your question, I think you're happy with daily frequency but instead will need to optimise around the decision strategy and building the vol surfaces at each period. I don't know of any package that is built for this, but would love to hear if there is anything out there.

Comment: @StackG I dont even wanna optimize anything, just wanna see what happens if i roll backspreads on that signal historically.

Comment: @Chris well I am not that computer savy

Comment: To help you clarify the question: I think what we are trying to say is, do you want help with the backtesting part (looping over historic prices and making decisions) or the options pricing part (building vol surfaces, determining what is 'atm vol' at any time and what those options cost)? These are two pretty different things

Comment: @StackG oh, sorry for being unclear, I just wanna run the strategy over historic data. In other words, see how a portfolio developed that put on the backspreads on the signal. Irrespective of anything, just as soon as market is down/up 5% over 30 days then put on a backspread in the direction of the move and let it mature each time.

Comment: Define backspread please

Comment: @StackG Added some info to question